# Can't connect to Authorize.net Test Account with ActiveMerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, activemerchant

I signed up for a test account with Authorize.net because you can't do test transaction with the CIM service except through a test account.

I am using ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetCimGateway, which works fine with my regular account. However using my test account api login info, I get the following error:

```
"message"=>{"code"=>"E00007", "text"=>"User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values."}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've read through the active merchant source and have found the following lines which indicate that maybe it is sending to the wrong api url:

```
  self.test_url = 'https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api'
  self.live_url = 'https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api'
```

As far as I can tell, there is no way to configure which url is used, but I've found this line:

```
url = test? ? test_url : live_url
```

which seems to set the var, only the method test? isn't defined anywhere so I can't see how to set it.

I'm confused. Anyone able to connect to their test account via AIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to make this work in case anyone cares, or can use this info:

https://github.com/moklett/active_merchant/commit/4784e80d05f241b02dd9e7eb5957778cc91eee57#commitcomment-593814

http://groups.google.com/group/activemerchant/browse_thread/thread/173ee6554498b20a/cc91dbe2fda51dd6

`ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.gateway_mode = :test` #detaults to `:production`, and will use test server